# Pickling of a namedtuple instance succeeds normally, but fails when module is Cythonized

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I have a namedtuple type defined inside a module consisting of two classes, foo and bar, defined in the module's only file, `mod.py`.  I am able to create instances of both foo and bar without issue and pickle them.  I am now trying to Cythonize it so that I can distribute the module as bytecode.

The module file structure looks like:

```
./mod.pyx
./setup.py
./demo.py
```

The content of `mod.pyx' is:

```
import collections

foo = collections.namedtuple('foo', 'A B')

class bar:

    def __init__(self,A,B):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
```

The content of `setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup( 
      ext_modules= cythonize([Extension('mod', ['mod.pyx'])])
)
```

I cythonize it using the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, which creates the compiled module file:

```
./mod.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
```

Running the following `demo.py`:

```
import mod, pickle
ham = mod.foo(1,2)
spam = mod.bar(1,2)

print(pickle.dumps(spam))
print(pickle.dumps(ham))
```

Successfully pickles `spam`, the instance of class `bar`, but fails on `ham`, the instance of namedtuple `foo`, with the error message:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'importlib._bootstrap.foo'>: attribute lookup foo on importlib._bootstrap failed
```

This is all done in Python 3.7, if it matters.  It seems like Pickle can no longer find the class definition of `mod.foo`, even though Python is able to create an instance without issue.  I know namedtuple has some weird behavior with respect to naming of the class it returns, and I admit I am a relative novice at packaging Cython modules.

A bit of googling turned up a few known issues with namedtuples and Cython, so I'm wondering if this might be part of a known issue, or if I am just packaging my module incorrectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for `pickle` to work, the attribute `__module__` of the `foo`-type must be set and should be `mod`.

`namedtuple` uses [a trick/heuristic](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L464-L475) (i.e lookup  in `sys._getframe(1).f_globals`) to get this information:

```
def namedtuple(typename, field_names, *, rename=False, defaults=None, module=None):
    ...
    # For pickling to work, the __module__ variable needs to be set to the frame
    # where the named tuple is created.  Bypass this step in environments where
    # sys._getframe is not defined (Jython for example) or sys._getframe is not
    # defined for arguments greater than 0 (IronPython), or where the user has
    # specified a particular module.
    if module is None:
        try:
            module = _sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')
        except (AttributeError, ValueError):
            pass
    if module is not None:
        result.__module__ = module
    ...
```

The problem with the Cython- or C-extensions is that, this heuristic will not work and `_sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')` will yield `importlib._bootstrap` and not `mod`.

To fix that you need to pass right `module`-name to `namedtuple`-factory (as pointed out in the code-comments), i.e.:

```
foo = collections.namedtuple('foo', 'A B', module='mod')
```

or to keep it more generic:

```
foo = collections.namedtuple('foo', 'A B', module=__name__)
```

Now, after importing, `foo.__module__` is `mod` as expected by `pickle` and `ham` can be pickled.

---

By the way, pickling of `bar` functions, because Cython explicitly sets the right `__module__` attribute (i.e. `mod`), while constructing the class.